# On compiling the below code compiler showing warning

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct employee
{
  char name[25] ;
  int id ;
  int age ;
  float inc ;
} b[3] ;

int main()
{
  int i ;
  for(i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++)
  {
    printf("Enter name , id , age , inc of employee %d :- ",i+1) ;
    scanf("%s%d%d%f",&b[i].name,&b[i].id,&b[i].age,&b[i].inc) ;
  }
  printf("\n") ;
  for(i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++)
  {
    printf("%s%d%d%f\n",b[i].name,b[i].id,b[i].age,b[i].inc) ;
  }
  return 0 ;
}
```

Output on compiling :

> warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument  has type ‘char (*)[25]’ [-Wformat=]
>        scanf("%s%d%d%f",&b[i].name,&b[i].id,&b[i].age,&b[i].inc) ;

How to fix the warning ?

Comment: No need for `&` on `b[i].name`

Comment: An array name, like `b[i].name`, will [decay to a pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying). No need for the `&`.

Comment: @KevinDTimm In `scanf` you do.

Comment: @HenriMenke - no, you do not

Comment: Have you tried referring to the C reference? There is even a working example: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/

Comment: @Nick - does the same exist for the `c` language?

Comment: Plus, your scanf may not store what you think it will store w.r.t. whitespace or lack thereof, etc.

Comment: @KevinDTimm - The C++ C library is largely the same as ISO1990 C; exactly the same for the purposes of this question. I just linked the first source I knew was reputable.

Comment: @Nick - as these are 2 separate languages, I would expect that there should be a page for `c`

Comment: Fine: https://www-s.acm.illinois.edu/webmonkeys/book/c_guide/2.12.html#scanf -- but now my eyes hurt.

Comment: @KevinDTimm Yes, http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf or http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/scanf/ for example.

Comment: @Bob__ : nope (C++ reference 
C++98, C++03, C++11, C++14, C++17, C++20)

Comment: @KevinDTimm Do you mind elaborate? I specifically linked to the C documentation page (see the references throughout the whole page and at the bottom in particular) even if that site is well known as C++ reference.

Answer (score 4):

`&b[i].name` is a pointer to an array of `char` (it's a `char (*)[25]`), but `scanf` wants a pointer to a `char` (a `char*`).

You need to pass a pointer to the array's first element.

You can either get that explicitly with `&b[i].name[0]`, or rely on implicit conversion  with just `b[i].name`

Answer (score 2):

No need for `&` on `b[i].name` as this decomposes to a pointer to the zeroth element already